# What is the "Tableau" way to deal with changing data?

Tags: tableau-api

***As a background to this question:*** I've been using Tableau for some time now, but I've been using code (Python, Swift, etc) as a crutch for getting some of the more complicated things done. My employer is now making me move what I can away from custom code and into retail software packages because it will make things easier to maintain if I get hit by a bus or something.

***The scenario:*** With code, I find it very easy to deal with constantly changing/growing data by using recursion. I know that this isn't something I can do with Tableau, but I've found that for many problems so far there is a "Tableau way" of thinking/doing that can solve a lot of problems. And, I'm not allowed to use Rserve/TabPy.

I have a batch of transactional data that grows every month by about 1.6mil records. What I would like to do is build something in Tableau that can let me track a complicated rolling total across the data without having to do it manually. In my code of choice, it would have been something like:

1. Import the data into a frame
2. For every unique date value in the 'transaction date' field, create a new column with that name
3. Total the number of transaction in each account for that day
4. Write the data to the applicable column
5. Move on to the next day
6. Then create new columns that store the sum total of transactions for that account over all of the 30 day periods available (date through date + 29 days)
7. Select the max value of the accounts for a customer for those 30-day sums
8. Dump all of that 30-day data into a new table based on the customer identifier

It's a lot of steps, but with a couple of nice recursive functions, it's done in a snap with a bit of code. Plus, it can handle the data as it changes.

***The actual question:*** How in the world do I approach problems like this within Tableau since my brain goes straight to recursive function land? I can do this manually with Tableau Prep, but it takes manual tweaking every time the data changes. Is there a better way, or is this just not within the realm of what Tableau really does?

**** Edit 10/1/2020:* Minor typo fix. ***

Comment: Nicely described question. Where is your original source data? In a RDMS? text files? something else? Do you have access to Tableau Prep Conductor? (i.e. did you purchase the Data Management Add-On for Tableau Server?) Trying to bound the potential solution space

Comment: The data is updated to our MSSQL server nightly, with daily incremental csv backups just in case. The core system doesn't let us access anything directly, and the reporting/extract system they have for it doesn't allow us to access historical data beyond 12 months. It's not ideal. We don't have the Data Management Add-On at this time, but if it provided a good solution what what we are trying to do, it could be on the table for consideration. I appreciate your thoughts. =D

Comment: What do you mean that “the core system doesn’t let us access anything directly”? Does that mean that the Tableau Server cannot connect to your MSSQL server and submit read-only select queries? Also, are your tables measured in millions of rows? billions? Quadrillions? (Some solutions are feasible for normal sized data but not practical for giant datasets)

Comment: It's in a system with an external vendor that uses a proprietary DB format. We then pay for a crippled version of IBM Cognos to access a set of data. This is very limited in how we can utilize it, so I run exports of the data I need as CSV files onto our network nightly, and our IT staff stuffs them into tables on our server. It's a mess, and I am powerless to improve it. Once it hits the MSSQL server, I can work from there. This particular data set it is currently at 15.5mil rows and grows at 1.5 mil  - 1.75 mil per month with growth at about 10% per year.